# how can we fetch data from excelsheet with react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, excel, react-native

I want to choose excelsheet from ios device (mobiledevice) using react native and fetch data i.e perticular row and columns from it and show data in flat list.I can choose and get excel file from device but I don't have idea how to read excel file and fetch data from it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

Comment: not working for me. Getting error like  "Unable to resolve "fflate" from "node_modules/read-excel-file/commonjs/read/unpackXlsxFileBrowser.js"